Table out of the border of the page

\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{Comparison of Different Camera Types for Mobile Robots.} % title of Table
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{adjustbox}{width=2\textwidth}

\begin{tabular}{ c c c c p{10cm}|p{2cm}|}

\hline % inserts single horizontal line
\textbf{Camera Type} & \textbf{Application Time} & \textbf{Characteristic} & \textbf{Advantages and Disadvantages} \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table heading
\hline % inserts single horizontal line
Monocular Camera & 2007 {[}70{]} & Contains only one lens, the basic unit of the visual sensor & Pros: easy to integrate, low cost. \newline Cons: cannot directly provide in-depth information. \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
Stereo Camera & 2008 {[}71{]} & Simultaneous generation of left and right images for stereoscopic visual & Pros: produces two images, can be used for stereo vision. \newline Cons: calibrates camera, computationally complex, limited depth estimation range. \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
RGBD Camera & 2011 {[}72{]} & RGB images and depth images can be provided directly & Pros: provides accurate depth information. \newline Cons: depth information is susceptible to environmental influences. \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
Event Camera & 2017 {[}73{]} & Uses pixel changes as events, captures luminance changes with microsecond time resolution & Pros: copes with high dynamics, scenes with large lighting variations, low power consumption. \newline Cons: requires image pre-processing for traditional info. \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
Light Field Camera & 2017 {[}74{]} & Adds microlens arrays to camera lenses to add scale information to monocular cameras & Pros: provides scale information for monocular cameras. \newline Cons: high computational volume, difficult to achieve real-time computing. \\ [0.5ex]
\hline %inserts single line
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}


Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment. This will allow us to see how wide your page actually is.

\begin{adjustbox}{width=2\textwidth}  that is forcing the table to be exactly twice as wide as the page, so naturally it does not fit. never use adjustbox on tables.

You've declared a tabular with 6 columns but you are using only 4 columns. IMHO you should remove 2 of the c and also reduce the width of the first p-column and maybe allow line breaks in the first column or maybe rotate the tabular. But without knowing more about the paper format and used font sizes this is only a guess. Not a guess but a suggestion: Using booktabs would be a good idea.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

Not really on topic, but what is [70]?  It looks like a reference to a citation, but if so, that's not the way to do it.

You've got to allow automatic line-breaking in all four columns. I suggest you employ a tabularx environment and set its target width to \textwidth.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' environment and 'X' column type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % macros to draw well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{calc}     % for '\widthof' macro

% for columns 1 and 2:
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\widthof{#1}}}
% for columns 3 and 4:
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize\hspace{0pt}}X}

\counterwithin{table}{section} % just for this example
 
\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{2} % just for this example

\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt} % default: 6pt

\caption{Comparison of different camera types for mobile robots.}

\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} 
     P{Light field} P{Application} L{0.75} L{1.25} @{} }
     % observe: 0.75 + 1.25 = 2 = # of X-type columns
\toprule
  Camera Type & Application Time & Characteristic & Pros and Cons \\
\midrule
  Monocular camera 
& 2007 [70]
& Contains only one lens, the basic unit of the visual sensor
& Pros: easy to integrate, low cost
\newline Cons: cannot directly provide in-depth information \\
\midrule
  Stereo camera
& 2008 [71]
& Simultaneous generation of left and right images for stereoscopic visual
& Pros: produces two images, can be used for stereo vision
\newline Cons: calibrates camera, computationally complex, limited depth estimation range \\
\midrule
  RGBD camera
& 2011 [72]
& RGB images and depth images can be provided directly
& Pros: provides accurate depth information
\newline Cons: depth information is susceptible to environmental influences \\
\midrule
  Event camera
& 2017 [73]
& Uses pixel changes as events, captures luminance changes with microsecond time resolution
& Pros: copes with high dynamics, scenes with large lighting variations, low power consumption
\newline Cons: requires image pre-processing for traditional info \\
\midrule
  Light field camera
& 2017 [74]
& Adds microlens arrays to camera lenses to add scale information to monocular cameras
& Pros: provides scale information for monocular cameras
\newline Cons: high computational volume, difficult to achieve real-time computing \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{document} 


The X type comment is probably only information if one knows that L is actually an X column

@daleif - The OP is always welcome to ask follow-up questions. :-)
